# How to get type annotation from stub files (.pyi) at runtime in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to get the annotations at functions or class methods.If the type hintings are written in the source code, then I can get types by getting attribute `__annotations__`.

```py
def hoge(n: int): ...
print(hoge.__annotations__)  # {'n': <class 'int'>}
```

But I don't know how to get types written in stub files (.pyi).

```py
# .pyi
def fuga(n: int): ...

# .py
def fuga(n): ...
print(fuga.__annotations__)  # {}
```

Is there any cool method?

Answer (score 3):

From [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files):

> Stub files are files containing type hints that are only for use by the type checker, not at runtime. There are several use cases for stub files:
>
> - Extension modules
> - Third-party modules whose authors have not yet added type hints
> - Standard library modules for which type hints have not yet been written
> - Modules that must be compatible with Python 2 and 3
> - Modules that use annotations for other purposes

So unfortunately, there's no way to obtain the annotations and how they are interpreted is left at the discretion of the type checker. And that has the side effect that there's no authoritative resource to verify if your type hints are correct.

The closest to that is [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Comment: Melvyn, your opinion is right. The way to get the type from the stub file at runtime will not be officially supported. However, I thought it may be obtained by some method, and asked a question.
It seems that `mypy` create the syntax tree and get type hints. If we get the syntax tree at runtime and compare it with the syntax tree of stub file, it will be possible to get a type hint. But, I gave up because it is too difficult.
Thank you.